# How to write a macro to do standard deviation on a column of data just before a blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, stdev

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vhSt.jpg)

I have managed to work out the mean by writing this macro

```
'This works out how many rows (another way)
Dim AV As Long, AVC As Long
AV = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
AVC = AV - 1

 ' This adds up all the data starting from row 2 to before the blank row
 Dim LR As Long
 myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown))
 LR = WorksheetFunction.sum(myRange)
'MsgBox LR

 ' So finding the mean
 Dim mean As Long
 Range("P2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = LR / AVC
 Selection.Value = Format(ActiveCell, "#.00")
```

which gave the result of 17.84 in cell P2

But when I tried to write the same to calculate the standard deviation, it returned a value of 0. Does it mean that I cannot use a similar coding below to do the job?

```
 ' Doing stdev on range
 Dim MD As Long
 myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("O2", Range("O2").End(xlDown))
 MD = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(myRange)
 MsgBox MD
```

Also, I cannot figure out how to copy and paste it and stop depending on how many rows are in column O. Really appreciate some help as I am very new to writing macros.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRUMQ.jpg)

Comment: `StDev_S` [Arguments can either be numbers or names, arrays, or references that contain numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835583.aspx). You have a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dim MD as Long` to `dim MD as double`.

Comment: @Gary You should accept answer of pcw that is the way of saying thanks here at SO.

Comment: Yes.. sorry I am new to stack... I just noticed the tick!! Brilliant, thanks for reminding me.